# Задано параграф: Hello, World!

Tags: jquery

Задано параграф

```
<p> Hello, World !!! </ p>
```

Реализуйте функцию, используя jQuery, которая сработает на click событие по тексту. Функция должна изменить цвет текста на "red" и размер текста на "30px". Для поиска элементов используйте $ В реализации необходимо использовать chaining

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("p").click(function(){
  $("p").css("red");
        .css("font-size","30px");

   });
});
```

Comment: На *Stack Overflow **на русском*** вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке.

Comment: Ни слова не понял, сори.

Comment: Задано параграф <p> Hello, World !!! </ p>
Реализуйте функцию, используя jQuery, которая сработает на click событие по тексту. Функция должна изменить цвет текста на "red" и размер текста на "30px". Для поиска элементов используйте $

В реализации необходимо использовать chaining

Comment: Нет примера кода. Не указана проблема. Похоже на попытку решения школьного задания чужими руками.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
$("p").click(function(){
  $("p").css("red");
        .css("font-size","30px");

});
});

Comment: что не так с приведенным кодом?

Answer (score 1):

В приведенном примере неверно используется `css()` функция `jquery`.

```
css("red");
```

Которая в варианте для установки нового значения принимает 2 формальных параметра - название css свойства и его значение. В коде примера передаётся лишь один параметр, что подразумевает возврат функцией значения указанного css свойства.

Кроме того чейнинг функций подразумевает их вызов одой за другой в виде:

```
 css().css().css().css()
```

При этом они не должны разделяться точкой с запятой.

Ниже приведён исправленный вариант.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("p").click(function(){
  $("p").css("color","red")
        .css("font-size","30px");

   });
});
```

Comment: почему  неверно? чем твой код отличается от кода в вопросе?

Comment: `.css("red")` заменено на `.css("color","red")` и убрана лишняя точка с запятой.

Comment: Вся необходимая информация должна быть непосредственно в ответе

Comment: _В котором не указано название CSS свойства._ - название как раз указано?

Comment: тут смотя как посмотреть, то что подразумевается как значение указано в качестве названия.

Comment: @Grundy спасибо за уточнения.  Я исправил ответ, постаравшись разъяснить указанные вами моменты.